# Como encontrar dado com base em outra coluna com Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Possuo o dataframe `dfa`:

```
id   nome  
1    jose  
2    pedro  
3    maria  
3    maria  
2    pedro   
1    jose
```

E uma lista com ids:

```
ids = [2, 3]
```

Eu quero um dataframe `dfb` que seja os valores de `dfa` filtrados com base nos valores de `ids`:

```
id  nome  
2   pedro  
3   maria
```

Inclusive removendo os valores duplicados em `dfa`

Comment: Vc está no Stackoverflow em Português, por favor, faça a pergunta em Português para evitar fechamento

Comment: Por que o seu `dfa` possuem todos os valores duplicados em ordem inversa e por que esses valores também não são duplicados na saída, visto que existem 4 valores com ids igual a 2 ou 3?

Comment: Porque um dos objetivos é retirar a duplicidade do dfa e colocar em dfb somente valores, cujo, esteja na lista.

Answer (score 1):

Definindo o seu *dataframe*:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> d = {
...   'id': [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1], 
...   'name': ['jose', 'pedro', 'maria', 'maria', 'pedro', 'jose']
... }

>>> dfa = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> print(dfa)

   id   name
0   1   jose
1   2  pedro
2   3  maria
3   3  maria
4   2  pedro
5   1   jose
```

Possuindo uma lista de ids, `ids = [2, 3]`, você pode utilizar o `isin` para verificar quais são as linhas que possuem o `id` na lista:

```
>>> ids = [2, 3]
>>> print(dfa['id'].isin(ids))

0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
Name: id, dtype: bool
```

E, com isso, consegue filtrar seus dados originais:

```
>>> dfb = dfa[dfa['id'].isin(ids)]
>>> print(dfb)
   id   name
1   2  pedro
2   3  maria
3   3  maria
4   2  pedro
```

Para remover os registros duplicados, basta utilizar `drop_duplicates`:

```
>>> dfb = dfb.drop_duplicates()
>>> print(dfb)

   id   name
1   2  pedro
2   3  maria
```